# Handling threads in JNI code

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I have a cache implementation in C++ that is accessed from JAVA code via JNI.
To allow concurrent access to the cache I need to lock it and I am confused what type of lock should I use in my C++ program? should I use JNI's montiorEnter/Exit as the threads that execute the jni code are java threads or std::mutex cacheMtx? Thanks

Comment: Do as much in Java as possible.  If there is a corresponding Java object for your C++ cache, just make the native methods that access the cache `synchronized`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16848282/native-method-synchronization.  If you have many reads and few writes, make the native methods `private`, then implement public data access methods and use something like a `ReentrantReadWriteLock` internally to your object.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here for a sample code where JVM is accessed from different threads.

http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-no-027/

In general, you want to make sure to gain access to JVM, use it, and then, release everything.

[image]

In your case, you migh have slightly different approach, as you probably won't call JVM back, but still, you can utilize pthread_mutex as you are inside the same shared library loaded from your JVM.